# How can I let the user draw overlapping colors in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, drawing

I am creating a [drawing application like this](http://itunes.apple.com/kz/app/coloring-book.-dino-baby./id493282539?mt=8), but I have one issue. The problem is that when I draw a line with one color and then draw a line with another color, it gives me combination of both colors where the lines intersect.

[image]

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    [curImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    CGPoint mid1 = midPoint(previousPoint1, previousPoint2); 
    CGPoint mid2 = midPoint(currentPoint, previousPoint1);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 

    [self.layer renderInContext:context];

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, mid1.x, mid1.y);
    CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, previousPoint1.x, previousPoint1.y, mid2.x, mid2.y); 
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.lineWidth);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.lineColor.CGColor);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    [super drawRect:rect];

    [curImage release];

}
```

The rest of the project is available [on GitHub](http://github.com/levinunnink/Smooth-Line-View).

Comment: It would be preferable if you posted the most relevant parts of your sample code here, on site. Make sure you indent it properly by pressing Ctrl-K after selecting the code.

Comment: Hey slhck, I will post the code in sometime. 
If possible, kindly give me your email address i will mail you.

Comment: You don't need to e-mail me. I have no idea about iOS development, sorry. I'm just helping out to shape your question and thus, get you better responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe have a look at blend modes.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CGBlendMode